# Applying the Implicit Function Theorem (constructing a function)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Let $\mathcal C$ be the locus of all points $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ that satisfy both $$x^3(y^3+z^3)=0\text{ and } (x-y)^3=z^2+7.$$
Prove that near the point $p:=(1,-1,1)$, we can solve for $y$ and $z$ as smooth functions of $x$. That is,  show that there exists an $r>0$ and $\mathcal C^1$ functions $f,g:(1-r,1+r) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $p=(1,f(1),g(1))$ and for all $x \in (1-r,1+r)$, $(x, f(x),g(x))$ lies on $\mathcal C$.

I know that I will need to employ the Implicit Function Theorem, but I'm not sure how to construct a function given the two equations. Also will I need to apply it separately to get $f$ and $g$ or can I get a function $h: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick you can only use in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose you want to solve two real valued functions simultaneously for roots, I.E. We have some $f,g$ and we want $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0$. Then we might as well solve 
$$ f(x)^2 + g(x)^2=0$$
Because in the reals, a sum of squares is $0$ if and only if each term is $0$.

Use this to reduce your problem to just a single equation and then use implicit function theorem to finish it off. Here, your two functions will have 3 parameters, but that's just notation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the trick but it doesn't actually work for this problem. When I took the partial derivatives, they ended up being zero at the point $p
$. I was however able to define a function $ F: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ by $F(x,y,z)= (x^3(y^3+z^3), (x-y) -z^2 -7)$ which works